# Remove paragraph mark from string

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a macro that finds all of the 'Heading 1' styles within my document and lists them in a ComboBox on a UserForm.

My problem is that the Find routine I am using is also selecting the paragraph mark (**¶**) after the text I wish to copy, and that is being displayed in the ComboBox.

How can I remove this from the string? I've tried useing `replace()`, replacing `vbCrLf`, `vbCr`, `vbLf`, `vbNewLine`, `^p`, `v`, `Chr(244)` and `Asc(244)` with `""`, but nothing has succeeeded. For example -

```
sanitizedText = Replace(Selection.Text, "^v", "")
```

Can anyone please help with this problem? Thanks.

Here is how my form looks -

[image]

Comment: If the paragraph mark is always at the end maybe you can just remove the last character using myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)

Comment: try Chr(182). http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @MiguelFebres, your suggestion here does the trick. Add it as an answer and I'll happily accept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `ChrW$()` for unicode characters:

```
sanitizedText = Replace(Selection.Text, ChrW$(244), "")
```

Or, if the paragraph mark is always at the end maybe you can just remove the last character using

```
myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments, the second of your suggestions here is working just fine for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I used `sanitizedText = Replace(Selection.Text, Chr(13), "")` successfully; `13` is the ASCII value for 'carriage return'.

Answer (score 1):

This tiny script replaces, in a piece of text selected in the document (i.e. marked using the cursor) hyphens that are at the beginning of a line. It replaces them by an improvised bullet point: (o)

The script searches for occurances of "Paragraph mark followed by hyphen".

I had a similar problem as in the question above, as I was sure paragraph marks should be 'Chr(13) & Chr(10)', which is equal 'VbCrLF', which is equal 'Carriage Return, Line Feed'. However, 'Chr(13) & Chr(10)' were wrong. The naked Chr(13) did the job.

```
Sub MakeAppFormListPoints()

'Replace list hyphens by (o)

   Dim myRange As Range
   Set myRange = Selection.Range   'What has been marked with the cursor

      Debug.Print myRange  ' Just for monitoring what it does

   myRange = replace(myRange, Chr(13) & "-", Chr(13) & "(o)")

      Debug.Print myRange  ' Just for monitoring what it does

End Sub
```

(I use this for adjusting text written in Word to the insanely restricted character set of the official application form for the European Union Erasmus+ programme to promote lifelong learning activities. Well, I learned something.)