# Word VBA: Remove Paragraph Marker

Tags: vba, ms-word, paragraph-marker

I have code that automatically detects certain text based on a selection and places onto a user form.

The issue I face is removing the trailing paragraph marker. (see picture below):

[image]

I have tried the following and other variations, but I can't remove the trailing paragraph marker:

```
Dim theText As String
theText = Replace(Selection, "^p", "")
```

Lastly, I know I can use `Left(Selection,Len(Selection)-1)`, but this will fail if the paragraph marker is not there.

Comment: I guess that `Replace(Selection.Text, ChrW$(244), "")
` should work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633904/remove-paragraph-mark-from-string

Comment: thanks @Vityata, but this `?instr(selection,ChrW$(244))` returns 0 :(

Comment: What about `?instr(selection.Text,ChrW$(13))`

Comment: Try using Chr(13) instead of ^p in the Replace function. ^p is only for Word's built-in Find, but won't work in VBA string functions.

Comment: money @CindyMeister! Thank you!

Comment: works @Vityata! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the paragraph in Word, use one of the following 2 options (the first works for the OP):

- `theText = Replace(Selection, ChrW$(13), "")`
- `theText = Replace(Selection, ChrW$(244), "")`

Answer (score 0):

As provided in the comments above this is the solution:

```
Dim theText As String
theText = Replace(Selection, Chr(13), "")
```